# why zero numbers not saved on csv format

Tags: linux, bash, csv

in my Linux machine I create the following simple CSV file

```
echo 13,3245,54,09,12,02,01 > example.csv

more example.csv

13,3245,54,09,12,02,01
```

so later I copy the file example.csv to my PC

and when I open the CSV file on my XP machine

I see that all numbers are:

```
  13 3245 54 9 12 2 1
```

why the Zero numbers not saved in the example.csv that opened on my win XP ?

in my Linux machine how to fix that in order to saved the zero numbers ? on the CSV sheet

Comment: You can check here: https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070714033452AAyhxdY I think it is not dependent on the OS type

Comment: What exactly are you using to view the .csv file on your winXP? Incase it's Excel: that won't render leading zeroes on the screen even when they are there in the file itself. What happens when you transfer the file to XP, open a `cmd` prompt, and try `type example.csv`, are the zeroes there?

Comment: only double click on the csv doc ,

Comment: no the zero not there !

Comment: open the cvs with notepad and check...

Comment: Your worksheet understands unquoted strings as numbers… so it converts them to numbers without leading zeros.

Comment: ok this is clear , but is there are some .. that can save the zero in the sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose to view leading zeroes in Ms Excel

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Keep-leading-zeros-in-number-codes-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7

Comment: sorry not clear what the link say

Comment: You can change the way excel displays the numbers in cells ;Please scroll down to "Use a custom format to keep the leading zeros" leading zeroes are zeroes present at the left of the number . eg:   '02' has one leading 0